# Is there a way to set default stored procedure parameter values with a calculation based on another parameter?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm making a stored procedure with three parameters: `@type`, `@range_min`, `@range_max`.

- `@range_min` should be, by default, equal to @type - 10000.
- `@range_max` should be, by default, equal to @type + 10000.

Is it possible to set these defaults in the declaration section of the stored procedure?

Something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_TEST
    (@type int = 100000,
     @range_min int = @tipo_mantencion - 10000,
     @range_max int = @tipo_mantencion + 10000)
AS
BEGIN
```

If this is not possible, is the best choice to use an IF to check if it's null and then set it to the default value I need?

Thanks!
(I'm using SQL Server)

Comment: I'd pass in `NULL` by default, and inside the stored procedure check for the range parameters to be `NULL` , and it they are, set their default values as specified

Comment: Hi! I will definitely do this, thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not possible and defaulting to null and conditionally setting the value is the usual practice.

For example:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_TEST
     @type int = 100000,
     @range_min int = NULL,
     @range_max int = NULL
AS

SET @range_min = ISNULL(@range_min, @type - 10000);
SET @range_max = ISNULL(@range_max, @type + 10000);

...
```

Comment: What a shame, is this the same in all sql databases or only in SQL Server? Thank you for the answer!